# Jquery carousel not being implemented

Tags: jquery, image, carousel

I am trying to implement a carousel onto my splash page using jquery.
The images are displaying on the page, however the carousel isn't being implemented.
Could someone check my code to see if I have made a mistake?

The images to be used in the carosel should be waterfall2.jpg, lake2.jpg and beach2.jpg

```
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css">
</head>
<title>
</title>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Link" id="nav-faq">FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Link" id="nav-about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Link" id="nav-jobs">Jobs</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div id="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Link" id="nav-home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Link" id="nav-projects">Projecs</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Link" id="nav-blog">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav-shop-li">
                    <a href="Link" id="nav-shop">Shop</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="fade">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/waterfall2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lake2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/beach2.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.fade').slick({
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 200,
          fade: true,
          slide: 'div',
          cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: It says;
Jquery is not defined - slick.min.js;

Comment: Also;
$ is not defined - index.html

Comment: Are you testing this on a server, or locally on a PC?

Comment: I am testing locally on pc

Comment: Do I need to have the jquery library locally stored or can I link to it?

Comment: You can link to it, you just need to specify the complete URL including the http:// protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing jQuery on a server and using a CDN (content delivery network) like jQuery or Google, you need to specify a complete URL. So this:

```
src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"
```

Won't work. But this:

```
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"
```

Will. The first option usually fails because the browser will insert `file://` at the start of the URL, and odds are you don't have jQuery there locally.

Comment: This change makes only the first image in the carosel display, the carousel functionality still isn't there. This did solve the jquery library link problem so I shall mark as correct. Thanks.